# cannot not find library files in Eclipse with GNU C/C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, arm

I have a project in Eclipse + ARM Eclipse plugins (http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/)
I set the path to the required libraries; when I expand the Includes node in the Project Explorer I see the libraries:

```
"${workspace_loc:/nrf51_sdk/nrf51822/Include/gcc}"
"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/include}"
"${workspace_loc:/nrf51_sdk/nrf51822/Include}"
```

with the missing library: "nrf.h"

but when I build all the project I get this error:

```
make all 
Building file: /Development/EHAL-master/ARM/src/ResetEntry.c
Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g -DNRF51 -std=gnu99 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ResetEntry.d" -MT"src/ResetEntry.o" -c -o "src/ResetEntry.o" "/Users/nullpointer/Development/EHAL-master/ARM/src/ResetEntry.c"
Finished building: /Development/EHAL-master/ARM/src/ResetEntry.c

Building file: ../src/system_nrf51.c
Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g -DNRF51 -std=gnu99 -MMD -MP -MF"src/system_nrf51.d" -MT"src/system_nrf51.o" -c -o "src/system_nrf51.o" "../src/system_nrf51.c"
../src/system_nrf51.c:36:17: fatal error: nrf.h: No such file or directory
 #include "nrf.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/system_nrf51.o] Error 1
```

As I am quite new in this environment, I am quite lost.
Thanks

Comment: Did you install that library (SDK) in your current workspace?

Comment: yes that is my workspace: /Development/EHAL-master/ARM/Nordic/nRF51/nrf51_sdk  and i copied inside: /Development/EHAL-master/ARM/Nordic/nRF51/nrf51_sdk

Comment: _"my workspace is"_ that library??

Comment: Here is the library:   /Development/EHAL-master/ARM/Nordic/nRF51/nrf51_sdk/nrf51822/Include/nrf.h

Comment: _"and i copied inside"_ That's probably not what you really want (are supposed) to do, to use it with your project. Install the SDK on your machine, and set the include file paths and library file paths along with the right -l<lib> options.

Comment: It would be nice, if you compose an answer for your question, explaining in detail, what was the reason for your problems, and how you actually solved it. This might be useful for future researchers. Otherwise I'd recommend you to delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after reinstalling the nRF51SDK and link again the libraries to the proper directory though the properties option menu of the project ->  C/C++ Build -> Settings ->  Cross ARM GNU Assembler -> Includes and C/C++ Build -> Settings ->  Cross ARM C Compiler -> Includes , and include all the required libraries.